# textarea height 100%-space for submit button inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I need to place textarea inside table cell with width=100% and height=100%-space for submit button at the bottom of the cell. Main problem with IE, it uses default value of height for textarea element.

Here is a sample how it should work:
[image]

[Jsfiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegEF/cAWBL/1/)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/cAWBL/2/

Comment: exactly, your variant looks OK in Crhome, but NOT ok in Firefox and IE